# Can I colorTransform a MovieClip but exclude specific sub-components?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, colortransform

Scenario:

I have floating islands that move around in odd paths. There are torches (nested movieClips) mounted on some of the islands. Sometimes a weather effect will change the color and brightness of the islands. Is there a way to change the brightness of the islands (parent movieClips) without also changing the brightness of the torches (child movieClips)?

===================================================

One solution that I can conceive is independently color adjusting all the child objects of each movieClip, instead of adjusting the parent object. This seems highly inconvenient and unnecessary though, so any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Well you could have used a container MC that holds both island and torch then just adjust the island colour when needed. Some logic like `contMC.IslandMC.transform.colorTransform = etc..` would affect island only.

Comment: I'm probably going to do that.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you need to exclude some parts of a movie clip (or other `DisplayObjectContainer`) from alteration applied to their parent, you need to rework your container structure. You can try applying a reverse operation to selected children (say, inverse color transformation), but note that not every transformation can be correctly inversed.